# R - Alternatives to, or fix for, LMERConvenienceFunctions, for use with LME4?

Tags: r, lme4

I am crossposting this from https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/488201/alternatives-to-or-fix-for-lmerconveniencefunctions-for-use-with-lme4 as it was suggested that people might have more relevant knowledge here.

Recently I updated from R version 3.6 to version 4.0 for my analyses, and noticed that LMERConvenienceFunctions stopped working. Specifically, I use it in conjunction with LME4.

Whenever I try to use the bfFixefLMER_F.fnc (backfitting of fixed effects in LMER models) or pamer.fnc (compute upper- and lower-bound p-values for the analysis of variance or deviance) for a LMER model fitted through LME4, regardless of dataset, I am met with the error "Error in pf(anova.table[term, "F value"], anova.table[term, "Df"], nrow(model@frame) - : Non-numeric argument to mathematical function". I have tried this on two separate computers with the same result. Now, as far as I can tell, LMERConvenienceFunctions hasn't been updated since 2015, so I'm not holding out hope that a fix is forthcoming.

I tried reverting to R 3.6.2, but found the same error using the versions of LME4 that were out shortly before R 4.0 came out. I have finally found the previous version I was using, so this will (hopefully) fix it for my current analysis, but doesn't help if I want to use the most recent version of R and LME4 going forwards.

Other functions of LMERConvenience (namely fitLMER.fnc and mcp.fnc) seem to be working properly, so it doesn't seem to be a systematic issue, but it is definitely one that significantly impedes my work.

Does anyone have any suggestions for alternative packages, or could anyone offer any advice on editing the LMERConvenienceFunctions package so that I can get the broken functions working again? I don't have any experience with changing the coding within packages, so would be starting from bare basics there.

I am also aware that there are some workarounds through adding extra code in my R script, as I did find in my searching for an answer that it had previously been a problem with the same package in 2014 (https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2014q2/022264.html), but I am not familiar with writing that kind of code, so would appreciate any guidance there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get some help from the lovely people working with LME4 on github; for anyone who has this issue in the future, there are a few things of note:

1. I have emailed the listed maintainer of LMERConvenienceFunctions asking for them to update the CRAN version so that it abides by the rules of CRAN. Hopefully he does this.
2. For a fix for those using LME4 and LMERConvenienceFunctions, but who are NOT also using lmerTest, recently the anova table headers "Chi Df" and"Df" were updated to "Df" and "npar" respectively (reasons outlined here:https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/528). This is an issue for LMERConvenienceFunctions because pamer.fnc called to Df, so needs to be updated to call to npar instead. Further, bfFixefLMER_F.fnc calls to pamer.fnc, so is fixed when pamer.fnc is updated. For anyone unsure how, I found the code using getAnywhere() and modified it, so just copy the code below and paste it once right near the start of the file:

```
pamer.fnc <- function (model, ndigits = 4) 
{
    if (length(rownames(anova(model))) == 0) {
        cat("nothing to evaluate: model has only an intercept.\n\n")
        cat("printing model fixed effects:\n")
        fixef(model)
    }
    else {
        dims <- NULL
        rank.X = qr(model@pp$X)$rank
        anova.table = anova(model)
        anova.table = cbind(anova.table, upper.den.df = nrow(model@frame) - 
            rank.X)
        p.values.upper = as.numeric()
        p.values.lower = as.numeric()
        for (term in row.names(anova.table)) {
            p.values.upper = c(p.values.upper, round(1 - pf(anova.table[term, 
                "F value"], anova.table[term, "npar"], 
                nrow(model@frame) - rank.X), ndigits))
            model.ranef <- ranef(model)
            lower.bound <- 0
            for (i in 1:length(names(model.ranef))) {
                dims <- dim(model.ranef[[i]])
                lower.bound <- lower.bound + dims[1] * dims[2]
            }
            p.values.lower = c(p.values.lower, 1 - pf(anova.table[term, 
                "F value"], anova.table[term, "npar"], 
                nrow(model@frame) - rank.X - lower.bound))
        }
        dv <- gsub(" ", "", gsub("(.*)~.*", 
            "\\1", as.character(model@call)[2]))
        ss.tot <- sum((model@frame[, dv] - mean(model@frame[, 
            dv]))^2)
        aov.table <- as.data.frame(anova(model))
        expl.dev <- vector("numeric")
        for (i in rownames(aov.table)) {
            expl.dev <- c(expl.dev, aov.table[i, 2]/ss.tot)
        }
        names(expl.dev) <- rownames(aov.table)
        anova.table = round(cbind(anova.table, upper.p.val = p.values.upper, 
            lower.den.df = nrow(model@frame) - rank.X - lower.bound, 
            lower.p.val = p.values.lower, `expl.dev.(%)` = expl.dev * 
                100), ndigits)
        return(anova.table)
    }
}
```

(You may also need to run the function script for bfFixefLMER_F.fnc separately again, to let R know that bfFixefLMER_F.fnc should be calling from the updated version of pamer.fnc)

3. For a fix for those using LME4 and LMERConvenienceFunctions, but who ARE also using lmerTest, you will need to either 1) use numDF instead of npar, or 2) replace "anova.table = anova(model)" with "anova.table = anova(model, dff = "lme4") in versions of lmerTest 3.0 onwards. This appears to be due to the anova.lmerModLmerTest function (added in lmerTest 3.0) overwriting what the call to anova() does, with a Type III Satterthwaite analysis listed before lme4, leading to it being defaulted to when dff is not specified.